# Inconsistent datetime across server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime

I have a MVC function like this below, which will return the serialized JSON object back to the client:

```
public ActionResult ReportSalesHeaderListRest(ReportSalesRestViewModel viewModel, int? shop)
{
    List<ReportGeneralDetailDto> rptSalesHeaderList = (
        from txSalesHeader in completedTxSalesHeaderList.OrderBy(x => x.TxCode)
        select new ReportGeneralDetailDto
        {
            ItemDate = txSalesHeader.CashierDatetime,
            ItemCode = txSalesHeader.TxCode,
            ItemValue = txSalesHeader.AmountTotal
        })
        .ToList();
    viewModel.RptGeneralDetailList = rptSalesHeaderList;
    return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The problem is, JSON() function added some hours offset to my "ItemDate" attribute, when I run this code on an Asia server, 8 hours will be added to it, so "05/04/2014 08:15:19 (dd/mm/yyyy)" will become "Date(1396685719823)", which is "Sat Apr 05 2014 16:15:19 GMT+0800" instead of the time I want.

Does anyone come across this problem and is there any way ask JSON() function not to add the offset to my datetime values? Thanks!

Comment: Is that an issue with `Json()`? Or is it that you have different servers in different time zones? You can use the `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` and `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` to make the necessary conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is an issue with servers being in different time zones. You can use the `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` and `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` to make the necessary conversion.